# how to change obj "th" style using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want change my seletion th style by jQuery.

I use this [mod](http://www.redips.net/javascript/table-td-merge-split/) to get the all item.

```
//cell list with new coordinates
cl = Object {0-0: th, 0-1: th, 0-2: th, 0-3: th, 1-0: td…}, id = "0-0"}
```

now i will change my style use this function

```
var $B= cl[id];
$B.css("border-left", "none");
```

but this function is not working

```
Uncaught TypeError: $B.css is not a function
```

What should I do?

Comment: Invalid Object. Syntax Error. `var $B= cl[id];` ==> `var $B= jQuery(cl[id]);` **Wrap in jQuery**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it with jQuery:

```
var $B= cl[id];
jQuery($B).css("border-left", "none");
```

---

When you use jQuery methods on core javascript then it will throw an error obviously. You just wrap it with jQuery to work with their methods.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `var $B= cl[id];` only yields the id, not a `jquery` object. So you need to convert into a `jquery` object before you can apply css attributes to it.

```
var $B= $(cl[id]);
$B.css("border-left", "none");
```